# DrawText does not work

Tags: android, image, canvas, bitmap

I can not understand why it does not work the DrawText method. I have to write a text on a photo that was previously cropped. This is the code:

```
mImageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmap = mImageView.getDrawingCache();
Canvas c = new Canvas (bmap);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
paint.setStyle(Style.FILL); 
c.drawPaint(paint); 
paint.setTextSize(20);
c.drawText("Some Text", 0, 0, paint);
```

the picture is cropped correctly, but I see no text on it. How so?

Answer (score 0):

The text is drawn *above* the y-coordinate. In your case, the text is drawn above the canvas.
Try changing your draw line to:

```
c.drawText("Some Text", 0, 25, paint);
```

You might need to do some calculations to get the coordinates right.

Comment: I tried but even so I do not see anything. how can I calculate? @niek

Comment: You're first  painting the entire canvas white (`c.drawPaint`), and then try to paint white text over it.